# Android force close browser or reset it programmatically 

Tags: java, android

I have a client who when the android app exits wants the browser to reset so whatever was previous there will be gone. I have tried opening a website in the browser when the app exits but all that has done is open a new tab. Is there a way to close current tabs or force close the browser to reset it?

Comment: What does your app have to do with the browser? If you used a WebView, it would go away automatically with the app.

Comment: I'm new to asking questions on the site, can I move the question or do I have to re-ask on the Android section. My app has nothing to do with the browser. The client would just like the browser to be reset on the exit of the application so that if a offensive website was last looked at it would change to something else or go back to the home page. I would like to do it programmatically from my app either from the main activity or from a service that my app also runs.

Comment: @Aitchehtee: If you're trying to do this programmatically then leave your question here, the Android Enthusiasts site is only for questions about using Android, not development. Perhaps you can clarify your application's architecture and what exactly it is you're trying to do. Do you just want to make an app that clears the Browser app's history?

Comment: @eldareathis: I am trying to do this programmatically. My app plays a video then exits. My client wants the browser to be cleared when the app exits so that whatever site the browser may be currently displaying is reset. This just a feature of the app. The app will not go on the market, and will just be for the default browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a client who when the android app exits wants the browser to reset so whatever was previous there will be gone.

Fortunately, what your client wants is not supported. Moreover, since there are many browsers for Android (just like there are many browsers for other operating systems), there is no single "browser to reset".

> Is there a way to close current tabs or force close the browser to reset it?

Fortunately, no.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking to close only the default browser or delete it's history. Is there any way to delete it's history? I should say it is android 3.0+

Comment: @Aitchehtee: You can attempt to hold the `WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS` permission and use `deleteHistoryTimeFrame()` on `android.provider.Browser`. I do not know if that is a permission that ordinary SDK apps can hold, though.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it did delete the history  but it does not close any current tabs. Thank you for your answer!